# zkemkeeper: Real time events not triggering on ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, biometrics, sta

I have been going bonkers over this one, I am trying to register the real time events in my asp.net mvc web application. but nothing seems to work.

UserController:

```
ZkemClient objZkeeper2 = new ZkemClient();
bool isDeviceConnected = false;
  public ActionResult GetLogs()
        {
            isDevice2Connected = objZkeeper2.Connect_Net("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 4370);
            if (isDevice2Connected)
            {  //..more code
```

ZkemClient.cs

```
  public bool Connect_Net(string IPAdd, int Port)
        {
            if (objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IPAdd, Port))
            {
                objCZKEM.EnableDevice(1, true);
                //65535, 32767

                if (objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 65535))
                {
                    // [ Register your events here ]
                    // [ Go through the _IZKEMEvents_Event class for a complete list of events


                    objCZKEM.OnConnected += ObjCZKEM_OnConnected;
                    objCZKEM.OnDisConnected += objCZKEM_OnDisConnected;
                    objCZKEM.OnEnrollFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnEnrollFinger;
                    objCZKEM.OnFinger += new _IZKEMEvents_OnFingerEventHandler(ObjCZKEM_OnFinger);
                    //objCZKEM.OnFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnFinger;
                    objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(ObjCZKEM_OnAttTransactionEx);
                    //for b&w
                    objCZKEM.OnAttTransaction -= new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionEventHandler(ObjCZKEM_OnAttTransaction);


                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


private void ObjCZKEM_OnAttTransaction(int EnrollNumber, int IsInValid, int AttState, int VerifyMethod, int Year, int Month, int Day, int Hour, int Minute, int Second)
        {
            string time = Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " " + Hour + ":" + Minute + ":" + Second;
//tried breakpoint here but no control is returned
            string text = "Verify OK.UserID=" + EnrollNumber.ToString() + " isInvalid=" + IsInValid.ToString() + " state=" + AttState.ToString() + " verifystyle=" + VerifyMethod.ToString() + " time=" + time;

           // return objCZKEM.OnAttTransaction(EnrollNumber, IsInValid, AttState, VerifyMethod, Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second);
        }
        private void ObjCZKEM_OnAttTransactionEx(string EnrollNumber, int IsInValid, int AttState, int VerifyMethod, int Year, int Month, int Day, int Hour, int Minute, int Second, int WorkCode)
        {
            string time = Year + "-" + Month + "-" + Day + " " + Hour + ":" + Minute + ":" + Second;
//breakpoints here do not stop
           string text = "Verify OK.UserID=" + EnrollNumber.ToString() + " isInvalid=" + IsInValid.ToString() + " state=" + AttState.ToString() + " verifystyle=" + VerifyMethod.ToString() + " time=" + time;

        }
```

I read somewhere I need to use STA threads, I did try but that did not help either.

Comment: Mick could you resolve it? Im experiencing the same problem. Thanks